# Deleting merged branches in GitLab periodically?

Tags: gitlab

I've searched some documentation but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

Does GitLab provide a feature which allows deleting all branches which have been merged recently? Either as a feature of GitLab itself or by using a third-party plugin or similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gitlab exposes [API resource](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#delete-merged-branches) to delete all non-protected branches merged into the project’s default branch (master per default).

To delete them periodically in gitlab, you can create a pipeline in a [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html) and [schedule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) it at the frequency you want.

Comment: schedule link is down

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/branches/#delete-merged-branches? Also, there's an option to remove the source branch automatically after it's successfully merged into master.